# Upgrading Play to 2.4, Slick to 3.1.1, value withTransaction is not a member of play.api.db.slick.Database

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.4, slick-3.0

I am trying to upgrade my application from using Play 2.3.x to Play 2.4.x (will end at 2.6, but going one step at a time) and Slick from 2.1.0 to 3.1.1.

I have done my best to follow [Play's migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24), the [Play Slick migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlickMigrationGuide), and the [Slick upgrade guides](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/upgrade.html).

One of the problems I'm having right now is with the following line:

```
val db: slick.Database = play.api.db.slick.DB
```

This no longer seems to be the correct way to do this b/c I get errors like:

```
value withTransaction is not a member of play.api.db.slick.Database
```

From the Play slick migration guide, it seems like I should modify this to something like

```
val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
```

But idk if I just don't have the right imports or what, but I get errors like:

```
object driver is not a member of package play.api.db.slick
not found: value DatabaseConfigProvider
```

For more context, here is one of the files I'm working with that gives this error:  https://github.com/ProjectSidewalk/SidewalkWebpage/blob/2c48dfa2e34c691e40568bfa9d50493aa3fe9971/app/models/attribute/GlobalAttributeTable.scala

Anyone know what I missed among these migration guides?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are migrating from slick 2.1.0 to 3.1.1. They have totally change transaction management. You can read about it here http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/dbio.html#transactions-and-pinned-sessions. I think you should check migration guide to 3.0.0 version first - http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/upgrade.html

Comment: Thanks! Yep I had also tried to follow the 2.1.0 to 3.0.0 guide. But the section that you linked to on DB I/O actions goes totally over my head. I am looking at my code like

`def getAllX: List[X] = db.withSession { implicit session => tableOfX.list }`

And I can't see from the upgrade guides how code like this should be migrated. Once you hit the 3.0.0 docs, `withSession` is never mentioned again. The best I could find is [here](https://grokbase.com/t/gg/scalaquery/15250knfya/slick-3-removes-withsession-dont-get-caught-by-surprise), but this doesn't explain fully either.

Comment: Okay here is another blog post I am finding helpful that gives more info on the migration of this particular syntax: https://anadea.info/blog/comparative-analysis-of-slick-2-and-slick-3 Will report back once I've tried it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing a few things:

1. I had not realized that I needed to use a more recent version of the play-slick library (I was using 0.8.0 still instead of 1.1.1).
2. I needed to add the import `import play.api.Play` instead of the import `import play.api.Play.current` that I already had.
3. I had an import `import play.api.db.slick` that was causing the "object driver is not a member of package play.api.db.slick" error at the line with this import: `import slick.driver.JdbcProfile`. I just removed the former import that was not needed.
4. As @Valerii said, `withTransaction` has been removed in Slick 3.1, and the replacement is documented in the various links in the comments above.